# Logstash Custom Plugin - Unable to create session to Neo4j within Logstash

Tags: logstash, neo4j.rb

I am having issues with a custom plugin and not exactly where to turn.

I am building a custom Logstash output plugin to build our Neo4j models. Running the code externally with jruby included with Logstash, I have no issues creating a session to our server. If run as a plugin, I end up with an undefined method error.

```
undefined method graph_db' for #<Neo4j::Server::CypherSession:0x3922b0a5>
```

http://pastebin.com/kV5rHxpF

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash version
logstash 2.1.1
```

Neo4j Community Version 2.3.1

Ruby Gem (Tested with earlier versions with similar behavior)
neo4j - 6.0.4

I can generate the error with the below plugin code.

```
require "logstash/outputs/base"
require "logstash/namespace"
require 'neo4j'

class LogStash::Outputs::neo4jGraph < LogStash::Outputs::Base
config_name "neo4jgraph"
def register
@session = Neo4j::Session.open(:server_db,"http://localhost:7474", basic_auth: { username: "", password: "" })
end

def receive(event)
end
end
```

Any ideas or direction I can look?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using jRuby, the `neo4j-core` gem is making an assumption that you want to use embedded mode rather than server mode.  We should find a better way to go about this, but for the moment if you use the `WITHOUT_NEO4J_EMBEDDED` environment variable with the value `true` it should load the proper files and fix your problem.

**EDIT:**

FYI I've made a pull request so that this can hopefully be easier: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/pull/244